# Error with Ruby Exception

Tags: ruby, exception

I have an array defined like this,

```
result = ["true","false","false","false"]
```

In my code I iterate through the array and raise an exception when i come across false.

```
begin  result.each  do |method| 
           raise  if (method == false) {
           rescue Exception => Form_Validation_Failure
                  puts "fail!"
           end } 
       end
```

There is an error when i execute the code.Is this is the right way to raise and exception in  Ruby? Could somebody help with this please.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to using strings in your array and the constant `false` in your comparison, I see a rescue inside braces.

I think the form of code you are looking for is:

```
>> result = [true,false,true,false]
=> [true, false, true, false]
>>
?> result.each do |method|
?>   begin
?>     raise if not method   # preferred to method == false
>>     puts "ok"
>>   rescue
>>     puts "fail!"
>>   end
>> end
ok
fail!
ok
fail!
=> [true, false, true, false]
```

Comment: It's also generally bad form to use `== false` or `==true`.  It's a boolean, just say something like `unless method` or `if ! method`

Comment: O noes you got me!  I've railed against that thousands of times.  Must... change... answer...

Comment: May I also suggest to @verdure to look into the Enumerable class, as methods such as `any?` could be a better choice than `each`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a string in the comparison:

```
...
raise if (methods == "false") {
...
```

Ruby has true objects for all and everything, so there is a difference between the string with the value `"false"` and the boolean value `false`.